# How to destroy CUDA graphics datatypes

Tags: c++, opengl, cuda, destroy

I create an OpenGL texture/CUDA surface pair from some RGB data with a function. The `cudaSurfaceObject_t`  can be used in a CUDA kernel for GPU-accelerated image processing, and the `GLuint` can be used to render the results of the CUDA kernel. The function is provided in the program below:

```cpp
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <cudaGL.h>
#include <cuda_gl_interop.h>

#include <iostream>



#define cudaCheckError() { \
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError(); \
    if(err != cudaSuccess) { \
      printf("Cuda error: %s:%d: %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString(err)); \
      exit(1); \
    } \
  }

void createTextureSurfacePair(int width, int height, uint8_t* const data, GLuint& textureOut, cudaGraphicsResource_t& graphicsResourceOut, cudaSurfaceObject_t& surfaceOut) {

    // Create the OpenGL texture that will be displayed with GLAD and GLFW
    glGenTextures(1, &textureOut);
    // Bind to our texture handle
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureOut);
    // Set texture interpolation methods for minification and magnification
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    // Set texture clamping method
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
    // Create the texture and its attributes
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,     // Type of texture
        0,                // Pyramid level (for mip-mapping) - 0 is the top level
        GL_RGBA,          // Internal color format to convert to
        width,            // Image width  i.e. 640 for Kinect in standard mode
        height,           // Image height i.e. 480 for Kinect in standard mode
        0,                // Border width in pixels (can either be 1 or 0)
        GL_BGR,          // Input image format (i.e. GL_RGB, GL_RGBA, GL_BGR etc.)
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, // Image data type.
        data);            // The actual image data itself
    //Note that the type of this texture is an RGBA UNSIGNED_BYTE type. When CUDA surfaces
    //are synchronized with OpenGL textures, the surfaces will be of the same type.
    //They won't know or care about their data types though, for they are all just byte arrays
    //at heart. So be careful to ensure that any CUDA kernel that handles a CUDA surface
    //uses it as an appropriate type. You will see that the update_surface kernel (defined 
    //above) treats each pixel as four unsigned bytes along the X-axis: one for red, green, blue,
    //and alpha respectively.

    //Create the CUDA array and texture reference
    cudaArray* bitmap_d;
    //Register the GL texture with the CUDA graphics library. A new cudaGraphicsResource is created, and its address is placed in cudaTextureID.
    //Documentation: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__OPENGL.html#group__CUDART__OPENGL_1g80d12187ae7590807c7676697d9fe03d
    cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage(&graphicsResourceOut, textureOut, GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsNone);
    cudaCheckError();
    //Map graphics resources for access by CUDA.
    //Documentation: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__INTEROP.html#group__CUDART__INTEROP_1gad8fbe74d02adefb8e7efb4971ee6322
    cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &graphicsResourceOut, 0);
    cudaCheckError();
    //Get the location of the array of pixels that was mapped by the previous function and place that address in bitmap_d
    //Documentation: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__INTEROP.html#group__CUDART__INTEROP_1g0dd6b5f024dfdcff5c28a08ef9958031
    cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray(&bitmap_d, graphicsResourceOut, 0, 0);
    cudaCheckError();
    //Create a CUDA resource descriptor. This is used to get and set attributes of CUDA resources.
    //This one will tell CUDA how we want the bitmap_surface to be configured.
    //Documentation for the struct: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/structcudaResourceDesc.html#structcudaResourceDesc
    struct cudaResourceDesc resDesc;
    //Clear it with 0s so that some flags aren't arbitrarily left at 1s
    memset(&resDesc, 0, sizeof(resDesc));
    //Set the resource type to be an array for convenient processing in the CUDA kernel.
    //List of resTypes: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__TYPES.html#group__CUDART__TYPES_1g067b774c0e639817a00a972c8e2c203c
    resDesc.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
    //Bind the new descriptor with the bitmap created earlier.
    resDesc.res.array.array = bitmap_d;
    //Create a new CUDA surface ID reference.
    //This is really just an unsigned long long.
    //Docuentation: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__TYPES.html#group__CUDART__TYPES_1gbe57cf2ccbe7f9d696f18808dd634c0a
    surfaceOut = 0;
    //Create the surface with the given description. That surface ID is placed in bitmap_surface.
    //Documentation: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__SURFACE__OBJECT.html#group__CUDART__SURFACE__OBJECT_1g958899474ab2c5f40d233b524d6c5a01
    cudaCreateSurfaceObject(&surfaceOut, &resDesc);
    cudaCheckError();
}


void initGL() {

    // Setup window
    if (!glfwInit())
        return;

    // Decide GL+GLSL versions
#if __APPLE__
    // GL 3.2 + GLSL 150
    const char* glsl_version = "#version 150";
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);  // 3.2+ only
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);            // Required on Mac
#else
    // GL 3.0 + GLSL 130
    const char* glsl_version = "#version 130";
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);  // 3.2+ only
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);            // 3.0+ only
#endif

    // Create window with graphics context
    GLFWwindow* currentGLFWWindow = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 720, "Raytracing in One Weekend", NULL, NULL);
    if (currentGLFWWindow == NULL)
        return;
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(currentGLFWWindow);
    glfwSwapInterval(3); // Enable vsync

    if (!gladLoadGL()) {
        // GLAD failed
        printf( "GLAD failed to initialize :(" );
        return;
    }
}


int main() {
    initGL();

    int size = 500;

    uint8_t* data = new uint8_t[size * size * 3]; //dummy 100x100 RGB image

    cudaSurfaceObject_t a;
    cudaGraphicsResource_t b;
    GLuint c;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
/*------ATTEMPT TO CREATE CUDA SURFACE AND OPENGL TEXTURE------------*/
        createTextureSurfacePair(size, size, data, c, b, a);

/*------ATTEMPT TO DESTROY CUDA SURFACE AND OPENGL TEXTURE------------*/
        //Destroy surface
        cudaDestroySurfaceObject(a);
        //Destroy graphics resource
        cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &b);
        //Destroy texture
        glDeleteTextures(1, &c);

        if (i % 100 == 0) printf("Iteration %d\n", i);
    }
}
```

There appears to be a memory leak in this program, as it causes the dedicated GPU memory to rapidly increase until the program crashes. What haven't I destroyed in the main function?

Comment: Without trying to ask the obvious, are you certain this really is a memory leak? There are a lot of operations which incur a one-time memory allocation that might look like a leak. It is also normal that freeing and destroying things doesn't free memory

Comment: @talonmies It appears to me as a memory leak. When I repeatedly allocate and deallocate the texture/surface pair with these functions, RAM consumption steadily increases to at least a few gigabytes. This happens in both the CPU RAM and the dedicated GPU RAM. None of the memory is freed until the program is terminated.

Comment: Update: this was a part of a larger project, and now I believe most of the problems lie elsewhere. When I isolated this code, the CPU RAM didn't increase significantly, but the GPU dedicated RAM increased to ~600MB after about 5000 iterations.

Comment: This question has now been rewritten with more concise code (i.e. a new program has been written just for the purpose of generating and destroying the three data structures many times), but the problem still exists and I don't have permission to open the question again.

Comment: I don't recommend this: `//Omitted for brevity`  What you have posted is not a [mcve] and it makes it more difficult for others to help you.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Ok, thanks for letting me know. The initGL() function has been implemented in the new edit, and it should work on any system with GLFW and GLAD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I add the following line:

```
cudaGraphicsUnregisterResource(b);
```

*after* this line in your code:

```
cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &b);
```

Your program runs to completion for me (i.e. it runs for the indicated 10000 loops) without throwing any errors.  It also runs without errors when running under `cuda-memcheck`.

[This function](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__INTEROP.html#group__CUDART__INTEROP_1gc65d1f2900086747de1e57301d709940) is the "destroyer" for `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage`.  You can get some sense that this might be the case by:

1. studying various CUDA sample codes (such as simpleGLES, postProcessGL, imageDenoisingGL, bilateralFilter, and several others) which use CUDA/OpenGL interop.
2. referring to the [runtime API docs for `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__OPENGL.html#group__CUDART__OPENGL_1g80d12187ae7590807c7676697d9fe03d), and noting that at the bottom of the function description it lists:

> See also:
> **cudaGraphicsUnregisterResource**, cudaGraphicsMapResources, cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray, cuGraphicsGLRegisterImage